# Concise string slicing in objective C

Tags: python, ios, objective-c, string

Is there any concise way to slice strings in Objective-C? So far I've got:

```
f = [f stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:NSMakeRange(0, 1) withString:@""];
```

Which is not quite as nice as Python's:

```
f = f[1:]
```

And would be even gnarlier if having to do something like `f[1:4]`:

```
f = [f stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:NSMakeRange(0, 1) withString:@""];
f = [f stringByPaddingToLength:(4-1) withString:@"" startingAtIndex:0];
```

Comment: "Concise" is an adjective rarely applied to Objective C :)

Comment: @MattWilding: this makes me sad =(. i miss my Python. xCode mostly makes up for it though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are probably looking for these methods:

```
- (NSString *)substringFromIndex:(NSUInteger)from;
- (NSString *)substringToIndex:(NSUInteger)to;
- (NSString *)substringWithRange:(NSRange)range;
```

For example, `f = f[1:]` becomes:

```
f = [f substringFromIndex:1];
```

and `f = f[1:4]` becomes:

```
f = [f substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(1,3)];
```

Just be careful that your indexes and ranges aren't out of bounds, otherwise an `NSRangeException` will be thrown!

Answer (score 1):

Try `substringWithRange:`. For instance

```
[s substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(1, s.length - 1)]
```

or

```
[s substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(1, 4 - 1)]
```